# How to validate field when create post

Tags: plugins, errors

I have a custom CPT and I need that my user fill all the required fields.
How can I check if the field is set and show a message error if is not set?

I have a custom hook to the save_post action that check if is my CPT, there is any action for show error box and prevent create post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check post data in $_POST array on [save_post_{custom_post_type_name}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) action hook.

And if data is not appropriate or according to server side validation and redirect page with custom error args using wp_redirect and , you can grab the errors and display admin notices using [admin_notice](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices).

Comment: Thanks @kapil, the problem is that the hook is execute even if is a new post so I get a loop. How can I execute that hook only after the submit event?